How do I remove old, possibly baked silicone from a stone counter top joint?
I am moving in a new place and they have this terrible silicone situation in the kitchen.
It seems burnt, it's not mold, it's not soft at all. It's super hard. How do I remove it? I plan to remove it and redo it myself. I really don't think that a utility knife will be sufficient. Will the caulk remover liquid work? Or should I try nail polish remover?
I added some pictures from the rest of the counter top. I thought it is silicone because the rest of the countertop has this yellowed transparent thing at the junction. It's really bizzare, but I am not an expert by any means, so I am not sure. The yellowy part feels like silicone.




What makes you think it's silicone? I've never seen silicone harden, and it typically has a temperature tolerance above 400 degrees, so it's not "baked". I'd have expected an epoxy here.

I removed the bit about your plans to replace the caulk. That's not relevant to this question. However, note that "soapy water" will do nothing to help with silicone mess. It's a solvent-based product.

If it is hard it's not a caulk. It's probably grout that will have to be dug/  scraped out with the accompanying possibility of damage to the counter.

I added pictures of the rest of the connection. I thought it was silicone because the rest is this yellowed transparent thing. It's really bizzarre, but I am not an expert by any means, so I am not sure. The yellowy part feels like silicone.

You can try a caustic and poisonous paint remover to soften that stuff, and to reduce adhesion to the counter, such as KleanStrip. Check a hidden spot to be sure the chemical does not attack the counter! That said, you'll still need a lot of manual scraping. Use elbow grease (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_grease).

The additionals pics show that there are multiple products use to seal the counter to the vertical surface so various methods will probably need to be used.

Could be a polyurethane sealant instead of silicone.  In any case, use a razor scraper against each of the two surfaces to remove it.

I agree with @RMDman - it does seem like it's multiple products. I guess I will just scrape a little bit at the time and see if I get anywhere. Thanks!

Single edge razor blade in a holder is the way to go. Keep changing blades so it is always a sharp blade doing the cutting/scraping.
